# Is there a possibility to update a Google Place via the API?

Tags: rest, google-maps, backend, google-places-api

#### Hello together,

I am curious if there is a possibility to **update a Place** in the Google Maps Platform **Places API** via a API request?
I can't find anything regarding it in the official documentation.

Or is the Google Places API really **read-only**?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Places API is a read-only API. If you are trying to edit a business listing you own, the [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business) may be worth checking out.